# Meteor onCreateUser generates 403 Signup Forbidden

Tags: meteor

I've seen several examples of onCreateUser for manually registering a user and from what I can tell all of my code appears OK, but I continue to receive the Signups forbidden [403] error upon creation. I've also looked at the documentation as per http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser. Thanks everyone for your help.

Here's what I have: ***ROOT>client>registration.js***

```
    Template.registrationStep2.events({

        'submit form': function(e, template) {
            e.preventDefault();

                var institutionID = template.find('#institutionID').value;
                var institutionRole = template.find('#institutionRole').value;
                var institutionName = template.find('#institutionName').value;

                var login = template.find('#login').value;
                var firstName = template.find('#firstName').value;
                var lastName = template.find('#lastName').value;
                var email = template.find('#email').value;
                var password = template.find('#password').value;

                var profile = {
                    firstName: firstName,
                    lastName: lastName,
                    role: institutionRole,
                    institutionID: institutionID
                }

                Accounts.createUser({
                    username: login,
                    email: email,
                    password: password,
                    profile: profile
                }, function(error){
                    if (error){
                        Meteor.log.error("Error Creating User", error);
                    } else {

                        Session.set("flashType", "success");
                        Session.set("flashMessage", "Your account has been created.");

                        Router.go('registrationComplete');
                    }
                });


            } else {
                // alert("Need institution");
                $('#needInstitutionModal').modal('show');
            }
        }
    });
```

I have `accounts-password` and `accounts-ui` installed and updated to the latest versions.

No matter what I do I receive this ***error***:

```
I20150709-13:43:17.545(-5)? (13:43:17) [ERROR] - Object: 
I20150709-13:43:17.546(-5)? {
I20150709-13:43:17.546(-5)?     "time": "2015-07-09T18:43:17.543Z",
I20150709-13:43:17.546(-5)?     "level": "ERROR",
I20150709-13:43:17.546(-5)?     "message": "Error Creating User",
I20150709-13:43:17.546(-5)?     "userId": null,
I20150709-13:43:17.546(-5)?     "additional": {
I20150709-13:43:17.546(-5)?         "error": 403,
I20150709-13:43:17.546(-5)?         "reason": "Signups forbidden",
I20150709-13:43:17.546(-5)?         "message": "Signups forbidden [403]",
I20150709-13:43:17.547(-5)?         "errorType": "Meteor.Error"
I20150709-13:43:17.547(-5)?     }
I20150709-13:43:17.547(-5)? }
```

Comment: See [accounts_config](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_config). I'm guessing you're setting `forbidClientAccountCreation` to `true` somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out. 
In order to do this I had to move the Accounts.createUser function to the server side (server.js side in server folder) and call it as a Meteor.method call.